# Не получается вывести коды стран. pygal.i18n

Tags: python

```
from pygal.i18n import COUNTRIES
for country_code in sorted(COUNTRIES.keys()):
    print(country_code, COUNTRIES[country_code])
вывод:
Traceback (most recent call last):
..
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygal.i18n'
```

---

Хотя я устанавливал pygal-maps-world.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35772027/11334182

Comment: Спасибо!читал, но так и не понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пояснение того ответа по ссылке. Нужно установить `pygal_maps_world`:

```
pip install pygal_maps_world
```

После этого нужно перезапустить среду выполнения, если вы используете Jupyter Notebook. И далее после такого импорта ваш код будет работать (в Google Colab работает):

```
from pygal.maps.world import COUNTRIES

for country_code in sorted(COUNTRIES.keys()):
    print(country_code, COUNTRIES[country_code])
```

Вывод:

```
ad Andorra
ae United Arab Emirates
af Afghanistan
al Albania
...
```

Comment: Cпсибо! Заработала. я пищу коды в пайчарме. Но почему то в слове " world"  и " COUNTRIES" выдает синтактическую ошибку, то есть выходят красные зигзаги. А так все норма.